# Are DVI cables considered D-Sub?

Tags: dvi, connector, standards

So DVI cables have the same D shell and mounting points as D-Sub cables, but have a very unique pinout that doesn't seem compliant with the D-Sub design.

Does this still count as a D-Sub cable? And if so what's the D-sub name of the cable (ex: RS-232 is DE-9, VGA is DE-15)? Does it even have one?

Comment: Found the specification on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20120813201146/http://www.ddwg.org/lib/dvi_10.pdf). I don't see anything mentioning the similarity to D-sub

Comment: D-sub and dvi are completely different.

Comment: @Moab how so? As far as I understand [D-sub is a loose standard adopting multiple cable types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#Description,_nomenclature,_and_variants). It even includes variants like [13W3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DB13W3)

Comment: (More on the spec) In the Acknowledgement page of the spec (page 2 of 76), Molex is acknowledged as author along with Silicon Image, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Display_Working_Group), Molex was never part of the group. Molex is also the author of 2 of the DVI patents referenced in the spec (I'll link the patents in the next comments - uspto.gov links have too many characters)

Comment: [4740180](https://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=4740180.PN.&OS=PN/4740180&RS=PN/4740180) and [5102353](https://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=5102353.PN.&OS=PN/5102353&RS=PN/5102353)

Comment: Some specs maintained for D-sub connectors: US Military MIL-DTL-24308 and International IEC 60807-3/DIN 41652

Comment: It seems that patent 5102353 is more relevant to the answer as it describes the housing of the connector

Comment: @DaMaxContent - D-Sub and DVI are not compatible and completely different standards. One is analog and the other can be digital or analog depending on the cable itself. The reason it doesn’t seem compliant is because DVI is compliant with its own standards and not compliant with D-Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DVI connector is not considered to be a type of D-sub connector. D-sub connector sizes are denoted by A, B, C, D or E. [The width of a DVI connector is 24.03mm](https://components101.com/connectors/dvi-connector), while the [closest D-sub width (B) is 25.04](http://www.interfacebus.com/Connector_D-Sub_Mechanical_Dimensions.html). The shapes of the connectors seem to be similar at first glance, but are certainly different upon closer inspection:

[image: Different video connector types]

It is not true that DVI cannot carry analog signals: DVI has three cable types (DVI-A, DVI-D and DVI-I) and all but DVI-D can carry analog signals. In fact, the analog pins on DVI-A and DVI-I connectors are pin-compatible with VGA, which is why you can connect VGA monitors to DVI outputs through a passive adapter.

Comment: Where did you get that drawing?

Comment: I'd also add that D-sub carries both too. SMPTE 274M is an example of a DB-25 that carries digital signals and VGA is an example of a DE-15 that carries analog.